# Retrieve generic class from collection based on another type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core, polymorphism

I'm having trouble implementing a solution for encapsulating some CRUD logic and dto-entity mappings inside a separate service and really could use some help.

So let's say we have next interface that provides access endpoints to the data storage and we're having a separate client per entity

```
public interface IClient<T> where T : class
{
    T Get();
    void Set(T entity);
}
```

And then we have ClientService that serves as an aggregator to provide a single access point to all the existing clients

```
public class A { };
public class B { };

public class ClientService
{
    private IDictionary<Type, object> _clientDict;

    public ClientService(IClient<A> clientA, IClient<B> clientB)
    {
        _clientDict = new Dictionary<Type, object>
        {
            { typeof(A), clientA },
            { typeof(B), clientB }
        };
    }

    public T Get<T>() where T : class
    {
        var client = this.GetClient<T>();
        return client.Get();
    }

    public void Set<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        var client = this.GetClient<T>();
        client.Set(entity);
    }

    private IClient<T> GetClient<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (_clientDict.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out object client))
        {
            return (IClient<T>)client;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Everything is good so far.

Now the problem. I need to convert it to use DTO objects to work with `IClient<T>` while still accepting non-DTO models to the `ClientService`.
Pseudocode:

```
public class A { };
public class A_DTO { };
public class B { };
public class B_DTO { };

public class ClientService
{
    private IDictionary<Type, object> _clientDict;

    public ClientService(IClient<A_DTO> clientA, IClient<B_DTO> clientB)
    {
        _clientDict = new Dictionary<Type, object>
        {
            { typeof(A), clientA },
            { typeof(B), clientB }
        };
    }

    public void Set<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        var dtoType = GetDTOType(T);
        var dtoEntity = _autoMapper.Map(entity, typeof(T), GetDTOType(T));

        var client = this.GetClient<T, dtoType>();
        client.Set(dtoEntity);
    }

    private IClient<DTO> GetClient<T, DTO>() where T : class
                                            where DTO: class
    {
        if (_clientDict.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out object client))
        {
            return (IClient<DTO>)client;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

I do understand that since generics are being resolved during the compile time we're not able to make them dependant upon a variable but is there may be any other way in which we can get a client to work with, i.e. is there any way of how can we implement an `IClient<T2> GetClient<T1, T2>` where `T1` is `A` and `T2` is `A_DTO`?
Please note that end user does not have access to the DTO objects and so not able to provide it as a Generic type and everything needs to happen internally.

Is there any generic implementation or I'm just wasting time and should go with creating specific methods for every client implementation (i.e. `Get<A>()`, `Get<B>` etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to include your DTOs in your client service class. That will definitely get messy once your model starts growing. What you can do instead is use a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to convert the result from your service class to your dtos. It is pretty straightforward. You can have somethings like this:

```
public class A { };

public class DtoA { };

var source = ServiceClass.Get<A>();
var dto = Mapper.Map<A, ADto>(source);
```

See the link for more details.

Comment: thanks, but if you see I'm already utilizing automapper in my example : `var dtoEntity = _autoMapper.Map(entity, typeof(T), GetDTOType(T));`. My point is that business logic will not know about DTOs and so I wanted to see if it's possible to encapsulate the conversion inside the service in a generic way.